# method range of object _global failed when trying to use a String Object within Range object

Tags: excel, vba

I've been getting a "method range of object _global failed" message when trying to use a combination of range objects and strings.  I'm trying to iterate through several worksheets, copy and transpose each row from the worksheet, stack the transposed rows into a single column, then move to the next sheet to grab its rows and paste them to the next column over.

```
Dim CopyRng, pasteRng, Outnum, compsht As String
Dim myRng, PstRng As Range

For j = 5 To 10     
   For i = 1 To tot_centers
     Outnum = "out" & j
     CopyRng = "ThisWorkbook.Sheets(""" & Outnum & """).Cells(" & i & ", 2), 
           ThisWorkbook.Sheets(""" & Outnum & """).Cells(" & i & ", " & tot_days + 2 & ")"
     Set myRng = Range(CopyRng)
     Sheets(Outnum).Range(myRng).Copy  'THIS IS WHERE DEBUG HITS ERROR

     pasteRng = "ThisWorkbook.Sheets(""" & "Compiled Data" & """).Cells(" & ((tot_days * (i - 1)) + (i + 1)) & ", " & j - 2 & ")"
     Set PstRng = Range(pasteRng)  'AND I'LL PROBABLY GET THE SAME ERROR HERE
     PstRng.PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
  Next i
Next j
```

Comment: VBA doesn't support evaluating random pieces of code at run-time, and there's no need to take that approach here -  `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Outnum).Cells(i, 2)` works fine by itself for example

Comment: Why are you setting a copyrange with a string? Why not set it directly?  Also, your sheets are indeed named `out5`, `out6`, etc?  Also, don't do `Range(range())`.  Try `Sheets(Outnum).myRng.Copy`? Or rather `Set myRng = Sheets(Outnum).Range(copyRng)` then `myRng.Copy`?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (tot_days/tot_centers variable names need resolving)

```
Dim CopyRng, pasteRng, Outnum, compsht As String
Dim myRng, PstRng As Range, j, i
Dim shtOut As Worksheet

For j = 5 To 10

    Set shtOut = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("out" & j)

    For i = 1 To tot_centers '<< tot_days ?

        shtOut.Cells(i, 2).Resize(1, tot_days + 1).Copy '<< tot_centers?

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Compiled Data").Cells(tot_days * (i - 1) + (i + 1), _
                                                   j - 2).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    Next i

Next j
```

Comment: +1 Thanks so much for the help, Tim Williams and Bruce Wayne.  You two nailed it.  I was WAY OVER COMPLICATING it.  To clarify some stuff, yes, sheets were named "out5" through "out10".  They're populated from space delimited txt files in a folder that I import to their own sheets.  I had used the Set myRng = Range(CopyRng) because I pulled some bad advice off the forum to use a string in a range object.  (Won't do that again).  Much easier to use the variables directly in the statement.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who sees this post and wants to know how to open sheets, grab multiple rows one at a time, and stack them into individual columns, here's how the code turned out:

```
Dim Outnum As String

For j = 5 To 10     'use worksheets with outputs 5 through 10
    For i = 1 To tot_centers  'in this case, tot_centers was declared earlier in the code and is and integer I count from a sheet
        Outnum = "out" & j
        Sheets(Outnum).Range(Sheets(Outnum).Cells(i, 2), Sheets(Outnum).Cells(i, tot_days + 2)).Copy
        Sheets("Compiled Data").Range(Sheets("Compiled Data").Cells((tot_days * (i - 1)) + (i + 1), j - 1), Sheets("Compiled Data").Cells((tot_days * (i - 1)) + (i + 1), j - 1)).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    Next i
Next j

End Sub
```